# split string only at one single point

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, split

I my script I need to split a string from were the dash/hyphen is. And assign each piece to one variable.

Example:

```
Blue Oyster Cult - Don't Fear The Reaper
Jimi Hendrix - Come On (Let The Good Times Roll)
Molly Hatchet - Dreams I'll Never See
```

I think regex can do it with `[\-]+` but I am looking for a method that it does not make more than two variables.
So whatever string it takes, the outcome must be in only two pieces. I think the best approach is to consider only the first `-` (hyphen) in the string.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: String.prototype.split

Comment: In both `Java` and `Javascript`, for Strings there is a `indexOf()` function which takes arguments as splitter character/string and returns array. With `indexOf` you can find first occurence of the '-' and hence you can get `substring`

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: @OmSao Thanks for you comment. The issue with split is that it makes the array of any instance of the character. So for example if there are 2 hyphen in one string, the array's length will be 3. While I am looking for a solution that it only look for the first instance and left the rest in the second item of the array.

Comment: @yBrodsky, Thanks for the comment. please check the previous comment .

Comment: Please see the answer posted. It only breaks string at the place of first hyphen. If it's what you wanted, we can close this question by selecting the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do `.split(/-(.+)/)`

Splitting by `-(.+)` the matching group `(.+)` will help you get the second  group you need in it's entirety - since `.+` will **consume** all characters after the first `-` till the end of line:

```js
var text = "Hello world - This is super - easy and cool";

var parts = text.split(/-(.+)/);


console.log(  parts[0].trim()  );      // "Hello world"
console.log(  parts[1].trim()  );      // "This is super - easy and cool"
```

P.S: notice that above I use `.trim()` just to get rid of the string wrapping   whitespaces for regex simplicity and **demo!**... Although if `parts[1]` returns nothing (`undefined`) you'll get an error. So use wisely - or expand the regex to account for optional whitespaces after and before the separator `-` with `\s?`

```js
var text = "Hello world - This is super - easy and cool";

var parts = text.split(/\s?-\s?(.+)/);


console.log(  parts[0]  );      // "Hello world"
console.log(  parts[1]  );      // "This is super - easy and cool"
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it's not the `limit` argument that makes it work, it's the clever RegExp. If you remove the `2` argument it still works, but `parts` will have a third, empty string element when more than one `-` is present. (Personally I'd just do `var [artist, title] = text.split(/-(.+)?/);`.)

Comment: @Jordan great respond. although other answers are good and working, I would choose yours as it is very efficient. So you can submit it as an answer.

Comment: @DannyBoy Like I said, the magic is in the RegExp, which is 100% Roko's work. You should accept his answer, and if he wants to incorporate my suggestion into it he should feel free.

Comment: @Jordan thanks, I was mobile and in hurry :) actually it's even one char less ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go!!

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Hello world-welome to the-universe welcome.";
    var n = str.indexOf("-");
    var str1 = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("-"));
    var str2 = str.substring(str.indexOf("-")+1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str1 + "<br>" + str2;
}
</script>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

r    var string = "string - with many - hyphens";

```
var firstIndex = string.indexOf('-');
var result = [string.slice(0, firstIndex).trim(), string.slice(firstIndex+1).trim()]
console.log(result);
```

only makes a break on first - and replaces spaces at begin and end of a part with the trim function

https://jsfiddle.net/gLwm7Lwv/1

Answer (score 2):

You could use `match` (with a regular expression) to turn each string into a pair (array with 2 strings):

```js
const data = [
    "Blue Oyster Cult - Don't Fear The Reaper",
    "Jimi Hendrix - Come On (Let The Good Times Roll)",
    "Molly Hatchet - Dreams I'll Never See",
    "Gorillaz - 19 - 2000" 
];

const result = data.map( title => title.match(/(.*?)\s*-\s*(.*)/).slice(1) );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```